# Easy CSS "body→wrapper→column" - body take column backgrounds?

Tags: css, layout, background, containers, inline-styles

GOAL: Make first & last column backgrounds extend to edge of DOC **width**, maintaining inner wrapper on the content. So the **red will extend to the left edge, blue will extend to the right edge**, but the text will stay contained in the center.

ISSUES: variable #'s of columns, column backgrounds set with inline style. I want the outermost column backgrounds extended to the right and left edges of the viewport, but content to stay inside a wrapper so text doesn't lay out unexpectedly. See this youtube video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSj5fGAJBP0 )

Any ideas how to do this, respecting the 2 issues above? I imagine it will require extra markup.

EDIT: Here's an image to illustrate what I want to achieve:
[image example of background with columns and wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLPZZ.png)

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 600px;
 margin: auto;
}
.col-6 {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
 <div class="col-6" style="background-color: red">
  <p>content inside the first div. e word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Fof</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-6" style="background-color: blue">
  <p>content inside the second div. em Ipsum unorum et Malorum" </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

**A More complicated example to show the flexibility I'm looking for:**

```css
.wrapper {
 width: 600px;
 margin: auto;
}
.col-6 {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
 <div class="col-3" style="background-color: red">
  <p>content inside the first div. e word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Fof</p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-6" style="background-color: blue">
  <p>content inside the second div. em Ipsum unorum et Malorum" </p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-3" style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Highland_soldier_1744.jpg'); background-size: cover">
  <p>content inside the third div. em Ipsum unorum et Malorum" </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the limitations?  Theres a few ways you could accomplish this, but you may have to restructure the elements.  The wrapper seems unnecessary.  If you remove the wrapper width, and then put new containers around your text, you would have the columns extend to the edge of the doc, and then be able to manipulate the text so it is layed out however you want.  You could also remove the container width and change the padding of your column divs to achieve the effect you're going for... if I understand you right.

Comment: Been using the first method - see Youtube video in Q - issue is text laying out unpredictably when column width is based on the viewport, not on a fixed width wrapper.